# How can I detect whether a user has an iPhone 6 Plus in standard or zoomed mode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, iphone-6-plus, uiscreen

How can I detect whether a user has an iPhone 6 Plus in standard or zoomed mode?
Is this possible?

I've tried `[UIScreen mainScreen].scale` and it reports `3.0` in both cases.

Answer (score 17):

**WORKING SOLUTION:**

```
//Display Zoom mode
var isZoomed: Bool {
    return UIScreen.main.scale < UIScreen.main.nativeScale
}
```

**OLD SOLUTION (not reliable in some edge case):**

> var isZoomed: Bool {
> return UIScreen.main.scale != UIScreen.main.nativeScale
> }

P.S: Please do not confuse these features from the iPhone settings:

1. `Settings -> Display & Brightness -> Display Zoom`

with:

2. `Settings -> Accessibility -> Zoom`.

Here we check for the first type.

Comment: It doesn't work, unfortunately. 
12 mini zoomed: scale 3.0, nativeScale 3.515625 ✅
12 mini no zoom: scale 3.0, nativeScale 3.0 ✅

SE 1st gen zoomed: scale 2.0, nativeScale 2.0 ❌
SE 1st gen no zoom: scale 2.0, nativeScale 1.7066666666666668❌

Comment: @DarekCieśla that is a nice find. I didn't test absolutely all devices. I think this might be a bug with iPhones SE 1st gen, since all the other devices which I tested on, worked perfectly fine.

Comment: I just tested this on all available simulators in xcode 12 (including SE 2nd Gen) and returned correct results on all. I didn't test it on SE 1st Gen since it doesn't support iOS 14.

Comment: @Fouad SE1 *does* support iOS14 [...]. The comparison above returns false for SE1 because it is the only device that does not support Zoomed Mode, and thus its scale vs nativeScale is always the same. That being said, the code if safe to use on all devices, thanks @Starsky!

Comment: No! Simulators return different value with devices!

Comment: This returns true on an iPhone 13 mini with zoom off.  There has to be some environment value similar to `sizeCategory` Apple can give us?

Comment: @GarySabo Please check the updated answer. From my tests, it is more reliable, even for iPhose SE 1st Gen which doesn't have Zoom mode.

Answer (score 14):

There's a new member

```
[[UIScreen mainScreen] nativeScale]
```

which should do what you want. It's only available on iOS 8, so you'll need to guard it

Comment: This worked for me! Just had to add mainScreen(). "UIScreen.mainScreen().nativeScale". Very useful to get images from a web service by their width & height and into an image view :D

Answer (score 13):

`[UIScreen mainScreen].currentMode` reports:

```
<UIScreenMode: 0x17802f240; size = 1242.000000 x 2208.000000> // STANDARD
<UIScreenMode: 0x178226be0; size = 1125.000000 x 2001.000000> // ZOOMED
```

Answer (score 10):

The following code may be used to get `bounds`, `coordinateSpace`, `nativeScale` and `scale`, i.e. on an iPhone 6 Plus the `nativeScale` is 2.608 and when the device in run in Zoomed Mode it is 2.88 (note that it is different in the simulator):

```
UIScreen *mainScreen = [UIScreen mainScreen];
NSLog(@"Screen bounds: %@, Screen resolution: %@, scale: %f, nativeScale: %f",
          NSStringFromCGRect(mainScreen.bounds), mainScreen.coordinateSpace, mainScreen.scale, mainScreen.nativeScale);
```

Code for detecting iPhone 6 Plus:

```
-(BOOL)iPhone6PlusDevice{
    // Scale is 3 currently only for iPhone 6 Plus
    if ([UIScreen mainScreen].scale > 2.9) return YES;
    return NO;
}
```

or

```
 -(BOOL)iPhone6PlusUnZoomed{
        if ([self iPhone6PlusDevice]){
            if ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height > 720.0) return YES;  // Height is 736, but 667 when zoomed.
        }
        return NO;
    }
```

Note: If you are checking for iPhone 6 Plus, to adjust the user interface then don´t rely on `.nativeScale`, because the simulator and an actual device give different results.

Comment: I'm running my extension in the new Messages app which has been properly updated for the new screen sizes in iOS8 (e.g. one that is not 'zoomed'), and `screenScale: 3.000000`, and `nativeScale: 2.608696`

Comment: @barfoon what were the screen resolutions reported? As I live in a country without Apple store, I haven´t been able to buy the new iPhone 6 Plus.

Comment: nativeScale isn't to do with whether or not the app is being run in scaled mode: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25871858/what-is-the-difference-between-nativescale-and-scale-on-uiscreen-in-ios8

Comment: @HHHH Your right and I have updated the text to reflect that although the code is still valid.

Answer (score 7):

Updated macros from Paula Chavarría's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26150089/2797141) for iOS 8 (where `[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size` is orientation dependent):

```
#define IS_OS_8_OR_LATER ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
#define IS_IPAD (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
#define IS_IPHONE (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
#define IS_IPHONE_5 (IS_IPHONE && (MAX([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width) == 568.0) && ((IS_OS_8_OR_LATER && [UIScreen mainScreen].nativeScale == [UIScreen mainScreen].scale) || !IS_OS_8_OR_LATER))
#define IS_STANDARD_IPHONE_6 (IS_IPHONE && MAX([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width) == 667.0  && IS_OS_8_OR_LATER && [UIScreen mainScreen].nativeScale == [UIScreen mainScreen].scale)
#define IS_ZOOMED_IPHONE_6 (IS_IPHONE && MAX([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width) == 568.0 && IS_OS_8_OR_LATER && [UIScreen mainScreen].nativeScale > [UIScreen mainScreen].scale)
#define IS_STANDARD_IPHONE_6_PLUS (IS_IPHONE && MAX([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width) == 736.0)
#define IS_ZOOMED_IPHONE_6_PLUS (IS_IPHONE && MAX([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width) == 667.0 && IS_OS_8_OR_LATER && [UIScreen mainScreen].nativeScale < [UIScreen mainScreen].scale)
#define IS_IPHONE_6 (IS_STANDARD_IPHONE_6 || IS_ZOOMED_IPHONE_6)
#define IS_IPHONE_6_PLUS (IS_STANDARD_IPHONE_6_PLUS || IS_ZOOMED_IPHONE_6_PLUS)
```

Answer (score 5):

These option is used to detect iPhone Devices.

```
#define IS_IPAD (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
#define IS_IPHONE (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
#define IS_IPHONE_5 (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568.0)
#define IS_IPHONE_6 (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 667.0)
#define IS_IPHONE_6PLUS (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] nativeScale] == 3.0f)
#define IS_IPHONE_6_PLUS (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 736.0)
#define IS_RETINA ([[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] == 2.0)
```

Comment: Since iOS 8 `[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size` became orientation dependent and these macros are broken in landscape mode. Could be fixed by using MAX(width, height) for value comparisons. Please see my answer below.