# Knowing if "Display Zoom" is on

Tags: ios, zooming, iphone-6-plus

Is there a way to know if a user is using the iPhone 6/iPhone 6 Plus "Display Zoom" feature?
I'm talking about [this feature](https://support.apple.com/en-il/HT203073).

Comment: See my response for the similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65844985/8314394).
It is not using hardcoded heights and is more useful for any device size.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `[UIScreen mainScreen].nativeScale` witch will gives you 2.6f if normal, and 2.8f if zoomed on iPhone 6 plus.

Comment: See my response for the similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65844985/8314394)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the screen bounds for If screen zoom or not

```
<UIScreenMode: 0x17802f240; size = 1242.000000 x 2208.000000> // STANDARD
<UIScreenMode: 0x178226be0; size = 1125.000000 x 2001.000000> // ZOOMED
```

For Programatically check for that need to use below code.

```
#define IS_OS_8_OR_LATER    ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
#define IS_IPAD (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
#define IS_IPHONE (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
#define IS_IPHONE_5 (IS_IPHONE && ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568.0) && ((IS_OS_8_OR_LATER && [UIScreen mainScreen].nativeScale == [UIScreen mainScreen].scale) || !IS_OS_8_OR_LATER))
#define IS_STANDARD_IPHONE_6 (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 667.0  && IS_OS_8_OR_LATER && [UIScreen mainScreen].nativeScale == [UIScreen mainScreen].scale)
#define IS_ZOOMED_IPHONE_6 (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568.0 && IS_OS_8_OR_LATER && [UIScreen mainScreen].nativeScale > [UIScreen mainScreen].scale)
#define IS_STANDARD_IPHONE_6_PLUS (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 736.0)
#define IS_ZOOMED_IPHONE_6_PLUS (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 667.0 && IS_OS_8_OR_LATER && [UIScreen mainScreen].nativeScale < [UIScreen mainScreen].scale)
```