# How to determine in iphone6+ device display mode is Zoomed or Standard

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone-6-plus

Is it possible to check whether display mode of iPhone 6+ is Zoomed or Standard. I have googled and found some macros but they are not working.I have used this
macro.    #define IS_ZOOMED_IPHONE_6_PLUS (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 667.0 && IS_OS_8_OR_LATER && [UIScreen mainScreen].nativeScale < [UIScreen mainScreen].scale) 
and [UIScreen mainScreen].nativeScale is 2.88 in Zoomed mode and 2.6 in standard condition.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Update your question with what you have tried and explain what issue you've had.

Comment: @ramddy, this que is alraedy asked but the ans given is not working for me.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I also need to check for zoomed mode

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65844985/8314394) is the answer to this question.