# How can I detect when display zoom is changed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, autolayout

I can't find how can I detect in code when display zoom is changed from the device Settings:

[image]

[image]

Because when the `Display Zoom` is `Standard`, all the `AutoLayout` works perfectly and when is `Zoomed`all the `UIView`s and `UILabel`s overlaps each other and I can't find a way on code to detect when is `Zoomed` to hide some `UIView`s and some `UILabel`s

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25952243/how-can-i-detect-whether-a-user-has-an-iphone-6-plus-in-standard-or-zoomed-mode