# SwiftUI: Detect Display Zoom is on?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uiaccessibility, accessibility-api

This question has been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25952243/how-can-i-detect-whether-a-user-has-an-iphone-6-plus-in-standard-or-zoomed-mode) but none of the solutions work.  I can't believe that in SwiftUI, similar to `@Environment(\.sizeCategory) var sizeCategory` there isn't a similar environment variable that we can observe and switch on?

Comment: Doesn't `\.displayScale` work for you?

Comment: @Asperi I tried `displayScale` but on my iPhone 13 mini whether I am in standard or zoomed Display, they both return displayScale - 3.0?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This was working for me (from that other post you referenced):

```
private var isZoomed: Bool {
    UIScreen.main.scale < UIScreen.main.nativeScale
}
```

I am also using this to determine if bold is toggled on in the accessibility settings.

```
@Environment(\.legibilityWeight)
private var legibilityWeight
```

with a combination of the text size:

```
@Environment(\.sizeCategory)
private var sizeCategory
```

I adjust the UI when it becomes too narrow and text too big to fit the text I want.