# Location wrong in touchesBegan

Tags: ios, iphone, location, touchesbegan, glkview

So I am using GLKViewController and GLKView.  I am debugging my app on iPhone 5s and if I view the drawableHeight and drawableWidth for the view it shows as 1136 and 640 which is correct for iphone 5s.  However when I check the following code.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
    self.lastGestureTime = startTime;
    active = true;
    UITouch *touch = [ touches anyObject ];
    CGPoint _location = [ touch locationInView:self.view ];
```

and I click the bottom-right of the screen I get the location as 316 and 533 which is approximately half of what I expect the co-ordinates to be.   So the location anywhere on the screen is getting sized to exactly half of what I expect it to be.  My UI displays correctly so the buttons are all in the right place, but the location from locationInView comes out wrong ( I think it is exactly half of what it should be ).   Any help would be great.

Comment: Did you heard about `scale` ... and why the `scale` it's 2 for iPhone 5s? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScreen_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScreen/scale

Comment: So... {316,533} * `scale` -> {632,1066}

Comment: I did some digging around and found that [ view.layer.contentsScale ] = 2.0.
So I adjusted the code as follows and it seems to work.  Not entirely sure if I need to be setting contentsScale to 1 for GLKView or whether let it remain 2 and then adjust my code like below:
    float contentScaleFactor = [ self.view.layer contentsScale ];
Vector2 location;
    location.v[0] = _location.x * contentScaleFactor;
    location.v[1] = _location.y * contentScaleFactor;

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25872821/1702413