# Use iPhone 6/6s/7 Plus' Native Resolution

Tags: ios, iphone, resolution

I'm creating an app that uses pixel-art style graphics, and I'd like to avoid the "Plus-class" iPhones' downscaling from 1242x2208 to 1080x1920 in order to avoid resampling artifacts. I know iOS bypasses the scaling when it plays full screen video. Private APIs are fine (not targeting the App Store) and I'm using OpenGL with GLKView to render, if that's relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
glkView.contentScaleFactor = UIScreen.main.nativeScale
```

See the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25871858/what-is-the-difference-between-nativescale-and-scale-on-uiscreen-in-ios8) for more information.

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it as soon as I can test on a Plus device.