# iPhone 6 - @2x, @3x - edge-to-edge image sizes?

Tags: ios, iphone, iphone-6

I'm a little unsure what image sizes I should be using if I want an image to go edge-to-edge in portrait mode on the iPhone (4S, 5x, 6, 6+).

Mathmatically it would break down like this:

- @1x = 320
- @2x = 640
- @3x = 960

Before the iPhone 6/6+ this would work for 1x and 2x, but the 3x and the fact that iPhone 6 uses the 2x graphics has left me confused.

By screen size it would break down like this:

- iPhone 4S, 5x = 640
- iPhone 6 = 750
- iPhone 6+ = 1242

I'm tempted to use images that are sized like this:

- @1x = 320
- @2x = 750 (and let 4S and 5x scale it down)
- @3x = 1242

Somehow this just doesn't seem right. So, should I simply go by the math and ignore the screen sizes, or go by the screen sizes and ignore the math?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25755443/iphone-6-plus-resolution-confusion-xcode-or-apples-website-for-development

Comment: I think you forget that iPhone 6 Plus and iPhone 6 have a *larger* screen size than iPhone 5 (these devices are NOT a scaled up iPhone 5). iPhone 6 Plus, on top of that, uses a greater resolution (3x instead of 2x on the design level). Ie the points size of a portrait iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 plus is NOT 320x568, it's something else, just watch http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions