# How to update my existing Xcode 5 Projects (iOS 7) for iPhone 6 Plus (iOS 8) screen size?

Tags: xcode, size, screen

i just opened my existing projects created with Xcode 5 for iOS 7.2.1 in the new Xcode 6 and executed these app on the new iPhone 6 Plus.

The Apps worked so far (except for some corrections due to the Location Manager etc.).

But the Apps view is just scaled to the larger screen. It´s not the native resolution of the 6 Plus.

When i create a **new** project and add some frame work UI elements like a Button or a TableView, then the native (new) resolution is used.

Which kind of settings has to be changed now to **adapt** the Storyboards in the **existing** Apps for the new 6 and 6 Plus screen sizes?

Kind regards

Edit:

I think i found the solution here:

[iPhone 6 Plus resolution confusion: Xcode or Apple's website? for development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25755443/iphone-6-plus-resolution-confusion-xcode-or-apples-website-for-development)

This is the hint:

**Note: Upload LaunchImages otherwise the App will run scaled and not show correct scaling, or screen sizes. In scaling mode the nativeScale and scale will not be the same.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iPhone 6 Plus resolution confusion: Xcode or Apple's website? for development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25755443/iphone-6-plus-resolution-confusion-xcode-or-apples-website-for-development)