# Screen resolution for iPhone 6 Plus is different from what apple says on its website

Tags: ios, iphone

Apple website (https://www.apple.com/iphone/compare/) displays screen resolutions for new iPhones as:

```
1920-by-1080-pixel resolution at 401 ppi //iPhone 6 Plus
1334-by-750-pixel resolution at 326 ppi //iPhone 6
1136-by-640-pixel resolution at 326 ppi //iPhone 5, 5s
960-by-640-pixel resolution at 326 ppi  //iPhone 4s
```

But if you print the screen sizes of corresponding iOS Simulators using `[UIScreen mainScreen]` the result is different for iPhone 6 Plus only:

```
1242.000000 x 2208.000000 //iPhone 6 Plus
```

Is it something to do with pixels per inch (ppi)?

**[Edit:]** *Thanks! I got the answer my first question. Please answer my second question below.*

One more thing. When I ran my existing app (developed for iPhone 5, 5s) on iPhone 6 Plus & iPhone 6 Simulators, it displays the screen resolution of iPhone 5 i.e. `640.000000 x 1136.000000`. But if I create a new app and print the resolutions it displays correct ones as mentioned above. What am i missing here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone 6 Plus resolution confusion: Xcode or Apple's website? for development](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25755443/iphone-6-plus-resolution-confusion-xcode-or-apples-website-for-development)

Comment: @n00bProgrammer Thanks for the link. Sorry I didn't see it. But can you please share some light on my second question

Comment: Even I have noticed existing apps are using the same points (320 x height). Haven't really given it much thought, but I'll research it a bit now, and get back to you.

Comment: to get proper resolution of device you have to add Launch image in Asset then you will get proper size of your device.

Comment: for more detail you have to check same link which is given by @n00bProgrammer.

Answer (score 0):

That number shows how many pixels you can draw on, but the iPhone 6+ actually doesn't have enough pixels to display that full 1242x2208 pixel image, so it downsamples the image until it fits 1920x1080-- and that's what it displays