# CGBitmapContextCreate gives EXC_BAD_ACCESS in iPhone 6+

Tags: ios, iphone, cgcontext, cgbitmapcontextcreate

When calling CGBitmapContextCreate method the app crashes giving EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

This happens only in iPhone 6+ (when running on on device).

```
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(baseAddress, width, height, 8, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
```

And yes, I've tried setting NSZombieEnabled to YES as an environment variable.. but still nothing is getting displayed on the debugger console upon EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a crash with this exact function because I was allocating a storage buffer with no respect to its alignment, e.g:

```
baseAddress = malloc (width * height * 4);
```

Now I use...

```
baseAddress = new u32 [width * height];
```

...to force a 4 byte alignment and it fixed the EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Note, I also use kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big instead of little as you are. May or may not be relevant.

However, I get weird pixel data back on an iPhone 6 and an iPad Mini.

(See [Getting pixel data on iOS 8 / iPhone 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26059049/getting-pixel-data-on-ios-8-iphone-6)).