# What is the relationship between naming conventions and optimization for bigger iPhone screens?

Tags: ios, resources, project

Upon researching on SO about optimizing my app to support the new iPhone 6/6+ screen sizes, I read about naming conventions like @2x and @3x, located in these threads:

[Image Resolution for new iphone 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25781422/image-resolution-for-new-iphone-6-and-6-3x-support-added)

[iPhone 6 vs iPhone 5 image naming convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26160951/iphone-6-vs-iphone-5-image-naming-convention)

I know that to ensure the app does not expand to fill the bigger screen, making icons and fonts look blurry, you need to include the LaunchScreen.xib file for the iPhone 6/6+ on iOS 8, and static launch images for anything else.

I achieved that and tested it on all the iphone platforms, and it scales fine. I named them appropriately as:

> Default.png Default@2x.png Default-568h@2x.png

But what about regular images I use as backgrounds, buttons, labels, etc? I just use plain old image1.png, image2.png, etc.

Do I have to follow the naming convention of image1@2x.png and image1@3x.png appropriately to be fully optimized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an Asset Catalog you won't need to worry about naming conventions anymore.  You can simply drag and drop the particular images for iPhone/iPad, 2x, 3x resolutions, etc. and the Asset Catalog will use the right image for the right device.

Here is Apple's documentation on Asset Catalogs: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/Recipe.html

Comment: maybe I'm not understanding, but I don't have multiple sizes of the same image. I set up constraints for image views, buttons, etc. and load the images onto them in the code. Then the images I have stored scales appropriately depending on the screen size

Answer (score 2):

I encourage you to use the asset catalogue - then it doesn't matter how you name your images. You just have to drag the right image into the right image size container (1x or 2x or 3x)