# Naming Convention for new iOS devices

Tags: ios, iphone, ios9, xcode7

I was looking around a tutorial over the internet for How to name the images for different iOS devices(iPhone 4s,5,5s,6,6s etc..).
We used to use for example imagename.png and imagename@2x.png.

But now we have iPhone 6 which have different resolution then iPhone 5s.

Can anyone suggest how to rename images.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26161544/1850983

check above link.

1x: iPhone 3GS and previous; iPod Touch 3rd gen and previous; iPad 2 and previous; iPad Mini 1st gen;
2x: iPhones 4, 4S, 5, 5S and 6; iPod Touch 4th and 5th gen; iPad 3 and newer; iPad Mini 2nd gen;
3x: iPhone 6 Plus;

Comment: So the question is a duplicate?

Answer (score 1):

iPhone 4, 4S, 5, 5s, 6, 6s use @2x images - even though the 6 and 6s have a higher resolution screen, they have the same pixel density.

iPhone 6 Plus and 6s Plus have a higher pixel density and use @3x images - however, the screen is rendered at a higher resolution (1242 x 2208) and then downscaled to the device's actual screen resolution of 1080 x 1920.

You can use a combination of autolayout and Xcode size classes to achieve your desired layout on the various screen sizes without changing your images - for example, users on the iPhone 6(s) and 6(s) Plus generally assume that apps will show more content on their larger screen rather than show larger graphics.

iPhone 6/6 Plus screen information: http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/iphone-6-screens-demystified

iPhone screen resolutions and pixel density: http://www.tekrevue.com/retina-display-comparison/

Answer (score -1):

iPhone 3GS and previous; iPod Touch 3rd gen and previous; iPad 2 and
   previous iPad Mini 1st gen --  imagename.png
 iPhones 4, 4S, 5, 5S
   and 6; iPod Touch 4th and 5th gen; iPad 3 and newer; iPad Mini 2nd
   gen -- imagename@2x.png
 iPhone 6 Plus -- imagename@3x.png