# iPhone 6 / 6+ Image sizes - Xcode 6

Tags: iphone, xcode

So I've just started using Xcode to make a game for iOS and I've been struggling with the whole screen size/background image sizes...

I've been reading a lot of questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25755443/iphone-6-plus-resolution-confusion-xcode-or-apples-website-for-development), but I don't understand what is meant by @3 and @2 etc?

I was under the impression if I account for the size of iPhone 6+, it would all just be scaled down/autofit iPhone 6... or visa-versus.

Comment: If your image size is 50x50 of 1x, then you must take 100x100 of 2x and 150x150 for 3x.

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to support for only iOS 8 and onwards on your game then you do not have to give different images for different device types.
As per the WWDC 2014 video titled "What's new in interface builder" Apple introduced support for Vector Images. You have to give the the image at 1x resolution and Xcode  will create the required images at compile time. I found this link useful for further understanding.

http://martiancraft.com/blog/2014/09/vector-images-xcode6/

On the other hand if you want to support iOS 7 also then you will have to give 3 sets of images for @1x, @2x and @3x. These numbers are scaling factors. Apple introduced newer devices with higher resolution it became necessary to give higher resolution images to keep up with the device resolution. So these sets of images are basically to be be displayed on devices with different resolution.

```
@1x - non retina devces like iPhone 3GS. iPad,iPad2 (not a complete list)
@2x - iPhone 4s, iPhone 5,iPhone 5s,iPhone 6,iPad 4 (not a complete list)
@3x - iPhone 6+
```