# Image Sizes for Supporting iPhone 4S,5,5C/S,6 and 6+

Tags: ios, iphone-5, iphone-6, iphone-6-plus

I want to support a variety of devices from **iPhone 4S** to **iPhone 6+**. Previously, when adding supporting for iPhone 5, we followed the following steps.

> 1. Add the launch Default-568h@2x.png
> 2. Use the same @2x images (640x960) which are resized automatically for iPhone 5.

Now, **iPhone 6** and **6+** are introduced with varying sizes and it is written on most blogs that we will use **@2x** for iPhone 6 and **@3x** identifier for iPhone 6+. It is also written that:

> 1. **iPhone 6+ (@3x)** images will have resolution of *1242x2208* (I am using portrait mode), and it is automatically downsized.
> 2. **iPhone 6** will use **@2x** images.However,I am not sure what the size of these images should be. Should they be *640x960* or *640x1136* or *750 x 1334*. In case of using the first two sizes, won't the images be distorted?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are after is detailed in the HIG under "Icon and Image Sizes"

- https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW1

Comment: I am sorry but I have gone through this link. I understand the default image sizes. However, My question mainly is "What should be the size of 2x images when supporting iPhone 4S,5 & 6. Should the size of 2x images be 640x960 or 640x1136 or 750 x 1334. In case of using the first two sizes, won't the images be distorted?

Comment: There is another very good thread on this on SO, at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25755443/iphone-6-plus-resolution-confusion-xcode-or-apples-website-for-development which hopefully will help more than my previous answer.

Comment: Can you kindly answer this simple question. I know that we need to use 2x for 640x960 (4S), 640x1136(5,5C/S) & 750x1334 (6). What should be the size of my @2x images. 1) 640x960   2) 640x1136    3) 750x1334

Comment: So, the simple (!) answer is your option 3 - 750 x 1334. The HIG states that "If you need to create static launch images for these devices, use the following sizes:

For iPhone 6:

750 x 1334 (@2x) for portrait
1334 x 750 (@2x) for landscape"

Comment: Can you kindly re-read my statement. I am not talking about launch images. I am talking about background images of other screen. In case of launch images, we can provide all of the above sizes.

Comment: Hi, sorry, I'm going to have to admit defeat on this one. Hopefully someone else can help you out.

Comment: Hi Gismay, It is not about victory or defeat. I just want to make sure that I am using the correct images. Thank you very much for your time. I really appreciate it.

Comment: This link is not the exact answer I am looking for. The +1 is for the efforts and taking out the time trying to help me

Comment: Did you end up finding the answer?