# Black bars appear in apps upgraded to work with iPhone 6/6+ resolutions

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, ios8

I recently upgraded my apps built with Storyboard using the previous iPhone 5 frame rectangles to work in native resolutions iPhone 6/6+ following the instructions provided in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25755443/iphone-6-plus-resolution-confusion-xcode-or-apples-website-for-development/25763870#25763870).

However, I am encountering a curious issue where the app would be fully native in iPhone 6/6+, but would have **black bars** appear on top and bottom when running in iPhone 5 (on both simulator and device).

I have tried by pinning all aspect of the view (when possible) to hug all corners of the view, but this still occurs. I am running everything on XCode 6.1.

---

**iPhone 6**

[image]

**iPhone 5/5S screen with black bars**

[image]

Comment: Do you have a launch image set for 4 inch devices? Afaik that's how iOS knows in which "mode" to run the app.

Comment: Thanks for commenting @muffe2k. I used the `LaunchScreen.xib` as recommended, and there doesn't seem to be an option to set multiple xibs to work with the different resolutions. Is there a step that I am missing here? Thanks again.

Comment: If your app supports iOS versions below 8.0, you still need static launch images for devices capable of running pre-8.0 versions (e.g. iPhone 5, iPhone 4s).

Comment: Thanks Ethan. Upvoted and great point.