# can an iPhone 5 image be used without resizing in iPhone 6

Tags: ios, user-interface, xcode6, iphone-5, iphone-6

In order to create an image asset for iPhone 5 and 6 do i need different sizes or should i just create an image according to the screen size of iPhone 5 and same image can be programmatically scaled to be used in iPhone 6

Answer (score 1):

The same image will be proportionally scaled for iPhone 6 automatically.

I'd suggest you to use images with 
@2x (retina) and 
@3x for the iPhone 6 Plus

This question and answer can help you and relate to your current question : [iPhone 6 Plus resolution confusion: Xcode or Apple's website? for development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25755443/iphone-6-plus-resolution-confusion-xcode-or-apples-website-for-development)