# What size image and ppi for iOS universal app

Tags: ios8, xcode6

After many hours of research I cannot find a clear, concise and easy to understand solution. I simply want to display an entire screen image and ensure the image I have uploaded conforms to the @1x, @2x and @3x format so the device will use the correct image.

I tried to wade through this answer [iPhone 6 Plus resolution confusion: Xcode or Apple's website? for development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25755443/iphone-6-plus-resolution-confusion-xcode-or-apples-website-for-development) but to no avail or understanding. Half the time the image is too big for the screen, the other time it's too small.

What size image do I load into @1x, @2x and @3x respectively to ensure the images fit correctly. Do I also have to alter the ppi?

Answer (score 0):

i think u can get some help here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconMatrix.html

http://www.iosres.com/

to get a universal image size is tough since the aspect ratio is different. iphone 5,5s,6,6+ all have aspect ratio of 16:9 but ipads have 4:3.
infact iphone 4 has different too.

Comment: Okay, so if I read these sites right it's not possible to have 1 image set that covers all sizes? In that case, any idea on how to have the code use the correct sized image? I'm simply trying to display a title screen.