# Can it be possible to use an animating View as launchScreen?

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, xib, launch-screen

I want to make a `launch screen` with a `animating view` so for that i have to use `story board or a xib/nib` because that is not possible by using `Apple's default launchScreen`. 
But when I going to do this use a xib as launch screen there is an`error`like `launch screen may not have connections`.
There is any other way to use a xib or storyboard as a `launchScreen`.
Any help will be appreciate.

Comment: The following link may help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27998284/launch-image-or-launch-xib-storyboard

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create launch screen with animation but you can create a fake splash screen view controller and add animation on it:

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9q1xd3wpqg2sx3p/TestLaunchScreen.zip?dl=0) is a sample project in which I used `LaunchScreen.storyboard` as... launch screen and in which I created a `FakeSplashScreenViewController` in `Main.storyboard`. This view controller is the root of my window. I put an animation in the `viewDidLayoutSubviews`:

```
[super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
[UIView animateWithDuration:3.f
                 animations:^{
                     self.myView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height); // implement your anim here
                 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     // Change the root view controller
                     UIViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
                     UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
                     AppDelegate* appDelegate = application.delegate;
                     appDelegate.window.rootViewController = vc;
                 }];
```

Comment: I ran it without any problem on XCode 7 (and simulator on iOS 9). What are the errors ?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is impossible to make by standard tools.
You may create simple screen, show animation, load remote info and call segue.
I choose this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a view controller instead and do what ever you want to do with it. but you have to first change Main Interface from LaunchScreen.xib to Main.[image]

Comment: not works ... only black screen appears and after that homeVC

Comment: did u make it initial controller.

Answer (score -1):

You can use below code . It may help you.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
         if(isAnimationShow)
         {
                //do code for show animation in ViewController file.
                ViewController *objlogin = [STORY_BOARD instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerVC"];
                [self pushViewController:objTimeSheetVC];
         }
         else
         {
               HomeVC *demoViewController = [STORY_BOARD instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeVC"];
               [self pushViewController:objTimeSheetVC];
         }
}
```

Comment: can you please explain it ??