# How to develop an app with multiple screens using xib?

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, xib

### I know this is a very stupid question.But I'm new to ios develop.And I even don't know the basic knowledge.

In Xcode 7.1,When I create an new project,storyBoard is default.I want to develop an app with multiple screens using xib files.Please tell how to do this?

1. how to set the launch screen ?
2. how to connect different xib files?

Anyway,could you tell how to build a simple project using xib step by step.Thank you very much.

Comment: Your english is probably what's preventing you from finding this stuff yourself. I googled "xib tutorial" and got [this](http://www.appcoda.com/hello-world-app-using-xcode-5-xib/), and I googled "xib launch screen" and got [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27998284/launch-image-or-launch-xib-storyboard). Google "view controller transitions" for your question about connecting different xib files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have multiple XIB,follow the below steps

```
     First remove the storyboard file from your project
     In Deployment Info of TARGETS,delete Main from Main Interface
     The create the View(XIB). Give the name as ViewController.Xib
```

Then in appDelegate.h

```
    import - #import "ViewController.h"
    @property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController *vc;
```

Then in appDelegate.m

```
    @synthesize vc;
```

Then in didFininshLaunchingWithOptions

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
   {
      // Override point for customization after application launch.

      self.window = [[UIWindow alloc]initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds]];
      vc = [[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
      UINavigationController *navigationVC  = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:vc];
      self.window.rootViewController = navigationVC;
      self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
      [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
      return YES;
   }
```

Next if want to crate multiple xib,you can create it with .h,.m and xib according to your requirements.

Comment: You helped me a lot.Thank you very much.

Comment: Please tick my answer if it is so helpful for you.