# Where to put launch images?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, launchimage

This has been an amazingly exasperating and non-transparent process.

So far, from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27310423/how-to-support-various-iphone-screen-sizes-as-of-2014) I have figured out the different dimensions of launch images I needed and that I can safely not use launch xibs / storyboards if I already have the launch images, and from various posts I have determined that the naming convention (*APPARENTLY??*) should be `Default@2x.png` for iPhone 4s, `Default-568h@2x.png` for iPhone 5, `Default-667h@2x.png` for iPhone 6, and `Default-Portrait@3x.png` for iPhone 6+, **although I have seen conflicting information on this so I'm not even sure....do I need `~iphone` appended to the names?**

BUT THEN, I go to add them to xcode so I go to my images.xcassets thing and select "new launch image" and this chart thing appears that makes zero sense to me....it only has space for one landscape picture, "Retina HD 5.5", but not for the other landscapes....even though the project is supposed to be portrait-only anyway...and if this thing is keeping track of my images then what do I need the naming convention for? This is so confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, the easiest way to make a nice launch image is to use a xib. You won't have to worry about naming conventions and it will scale beautifully across all your devices.

**Step 1:**
Your project should come with a file called LaunchScreen.xib. If you don't see one like that, hit File > new File > User Interface > Launch Image.

**Step 2:**
Open the xib and click on edge of the xib. Then, click on the Attributes inspector. Set the size to whatever you are using in the rest of your app. We are taking advantage of the auto layout and so the image should be resized to fit other devices.

**Step 3:**
Drag in an image view and resize it to fill the xib. Insert a high resolution version of your splash screen.

Comment: Unless you need to support iOS 7. Then you need standard launch images.

Comment: Wow, that sounded so great until this comment, which instantly put me back to square 1. This is how it's been for several days.