# iPhone 6+ splash images larger than native resolution?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Apple's guidelines for iPhone 6+ splash are stating a resolution that is larger than the native (physical) resolution

Taken from [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH22-SW1)

For iPhone 6 Plus:2208 x 1242

The device's resolution is only 1920 x 1080, anyone knows why Apple asks for a resolution that's larger than what the device is capable to show?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iPhone 6 Plus resolution confusion: Xcode or Apple's website? for development](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25755443/iphone-6-plus-resolution-confusion-xcode-or-apples-website-for-development)

Answer (score 1):

Simply because that's how the display works. The UI is composited at the higher resolution and then scaled to fit the physical screen. Presumably it was so they could create a new x3 resource size rather than have something weird like x2.67777.

Comment: I'd also link to this answer for more in-depth explanation of why it works this way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25755443/iphone-6-plus-resolution-confusion-xcode-or-apples-website-for-development