# iPhone 7 Plus background image size

Tags: ios, swift, image, uiimageview

What are the proper dimensions of a background image on iPhone 7 Plus? I have seen answers which indicate 1242x2208 which gets downsampled to 1080x1920 on-the-go. I cannot understand, why 1242x2208 is the appropriate size, since 2208px/0.66 (equivalent to 2/3) is not equal to iPhone 7's height (1334px). I know I can make my image be 1334px, it wouldn't be a big problem. But I don't understand the math behind it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iPhone 6 Plus resolution confusion: Xcode or Apple's website? for development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25755443/iphone-6-plus-resolution-confusion-xcode-or-apples-website-for-development)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Logically the device accepts input of `2208px x 1242px` for rendering which divided by `3x` retina factor ends up as `736 x 414` logical points frame. The downscaling by `1.15x` for the physical `1920 x 1080 pixels` happens in the iPhone hardware rendering pipeline. This allows Apple keeping the same frame coordinate system for `1x` `2x` `3x` screens.

Comment: As illustrated by [PaintCode](https://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions)