# How to calculate metric distance from CGsize?

Tags: swift, uikit

How can I convert CGSize to actual metric dimensions?
for example `CGSize(width:300,height:300)` on an 11 inch iPad is how much in mm?

Comment: You surely tried _something_. SO is not a free code writing website. Without showing at least some (research) effort, you're highly unlikely to receive an answer here.

Comment: @DávidPásztor I think the question is very clear and doesn't require any extra jargon that would just be overhead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It varies per device. You need to know screen resolution and pixel size. Just look them up in Apple's technical spec pages. Then simply multiply.  Don't forget to take into account different zoom levels (some devices can do this).

Comment: Good list here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25755757/341994