# iOS simulator showing different sizes on 7.1 than 8.0

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

With Xcode 6.0 I took advantage on the component options and downloaded the iOS simulator for 7.1 as well, now If I select on Deployment target "7.1" it lets me select iOS simulator 7.1, but there a problem with this note on the two pictures one with the 7.1 and the other with the 8.0 how the image shrinks, its this normal?

The only thing that I have changed on this projects its that I unchecked "Use Size Classes" and left it with iPhone only.

Please advice.

Thanks

**Updated pictures.**

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you saying you created a new project and didn't modify any code at all?

Comment: What's different about the two images? They look the same?

Comment: If all you did was run the simulator, you probably need to add new launch images as rmaddy explained in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25754395/xcode-6-gm-iphone-6-simulator-storyboards-not-sizing-correctly-appear-zoomed/25754487?noredirect=1#comment40274194_25754487

Comment: @ThomasW no, I just unchecked "Use size layout"
rmaddy see the black frames on the second images.

Comment: My guess is that you don't have the `Default-568h@2x.png` launch image required for iOS 7 and earlier to indicate that your app supports the 4" iPhones. And it works under iOS 8 because you setup a Launch Screen File (which doesn't do anything under iOS 7 or earlier).

Comment: @rmaddy: Why does have anything to do with the launch image? The application its fully loaded at that point, its just shrinked.

Comment: It has everything to do with launch images. The ONLY way that an iOS app (under iOS 7 or earlier) can support the 4" iPhone screen is by the existence of the special 4" launch image. Without that special launch image, iOS apps run in 3.5" mode on 4" devices. The black bars are added by iOS to make up the difference. This is what you see in the 2nd image you posted. This has been true since iOS 6.0 and the first iPhone 5.

Comment: It makes more sense now if you put it that way. No I was following the steps on the other post and I get to create the Launch Image set on the Images Asset, and I add a real image but same output.

Comment: Can you please edit the title to "iOS simulator iphone 5/5s showing different UIScreen bounds size on 7.1 than 8.0" ? it took me long time to find this post due to low google relevancy. 10x.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

@rmaddy is right.

You need to set a splash image instead of using the LaunchScreen.xib.
Go to your project settings -> target -> App Icons and Launch Images, change "Lauch Images Source" by clicking "Use Asset Catalog", select Images.

[image: you need to change this]
[image: select "images"]
[image: final result]