# Keyboard in not appearing correctly in web view - Landscape mode

Tags: ios, swift, webview, landscape

I'm presenting custom web view like this.

```
let vc = CustomWebViewVC.viewController()
    vc.delegate = self
    present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I've implemented this to show custom web view in landscape mode.

```
override var preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation: UIInterfaceOrientation {
    return .landscapeRight
}

//----------------------------------------------------------

override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
    return false
}
```

**Issue**

CustomWebViewVC is correctly opens in landscape mode but **when I click on textfield inside of webivew** this happens.

[image]

I don't know what is the issue is.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you test in real device ?

Comment: This is the screen shot of real device

Comment: Try any other site like FB. Check the same issue appear or not. May be webpage issue

Comment: I tried in device's safari there is no issue init

Comment: The same url in device's safari is working fine and keyboard is appearing correctly

Comment: Check the answer

Comment: you are not properly changed your orientation, see this for help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40466539/keyboard-appears-in-wrong-orientation-in-ios

Comment: additional help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26126823/ios-8-landscape-orientation-keyboard-does-not-display-correctly

Answer (score 1):

The missing method was this

```
override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.landscapeRight
}
```

After adding this in view controller did the trick.

To open viewcontroller in landscape mode you need to implement all three method as I did.

```
override var preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation: UIInterfaceOrientation {
    return .landscapeRight
}

//----------------------------------------------------------

override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
  return false
}

override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.landscapeRight
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add following code in `viewDidLoad`

Swift 4

```
let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeLeft.rawValue
UIDevice.current.setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
```