# iPhone6 (no display zoom mode) UIMenuController truncated

Tags: ios, iphone, uimenucontroller, iphone-6

I have a problem with the `UIMenuController` on my iPhone 6 when I use the standard display mode and device is in landscape mode. On iPhone 6 Plus the problem is in both modes. Maybe it's depends on screen resolution.

In that case, the `UIMenuController` will be truncated left and/or right. It seems that the `UIMenuController` can have maximum bounds as if the phone is in portrait mode.

See `UIMenuController` truncated (iPhone6 landscape schematic): 
http://imageshack.com/a/img631/8470/ozlaGe.jpg "iPhone6 landscape"

For me it seems like an iOS8+iPhone 6 bug. The code didn't change for a long time and worked.
In zoomed display mode, `UIMenuController` will be displayed correctly like on all other iPhones/iPads incl. iOS7.

```
... define UIMenuItems....
[self becomeFirstResponder]; // canBecomeFirstResponder returns YES;
UIMenuController *menu = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
[menu setMenuItems:items];

.. define frame...
[menu setTargetRect:frame inView:self];
[menu setMenuVisible:YES animated:YES];
```

**Fixed: see comment from Iliya Barenboim**

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that you didn't have launch images for iPhone 6 and iPhone 6+.

One other thing that I ran into when adding the launch images, is that there is a bug when doing this with an asset catalog. I added static launch images to my project and manually edited my info.plist as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25960203/378179.

Comment: Thanks!
That was the solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a compilation issue.  I ran the same code on the iPhone 5 iOS 7.1 simulator in Xcode 6.1, and the problem doesn't appear -- only when you run with the iPhone 6 / iOS 8 simulators (and, of course, on the iPhone 6 device itself).  So it's a problem with the iOS 8[.1] runtime.

Comment: This problem is only in iPhone 6 devices. It is working good on my iPod touch 5 with iOS 8.1.

Comment: Fixe via Iliya Barenboim comment!