# UIMenuController tap and hold zoom bubble fails in landscape mode

Tags: objective-c, ios8, uimenucontroller

Supporting iOS 7. (non-AutoLayout)

Running iPhone 6 (iOS 8.1)

[image]

The UIMenuController doesn't show in Landscape mode, in effect breaking the UI for my users.

What's causing this to break?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's the same problem that I have:

[iPhone6 (no display zoom mode) UIMenuController truncated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26506437/iphone6-no-display-zoom-mode-uimenucontroller-truncated)

The solution for me is to compile against iOS SDK 7.1. All others tries didn't help.