# iPhone simulator choose wrong launch image

Tags: sprite-kit, xib, simulator, launch

I've played with simulator and launch images and found some strange behaviour. Just for testing I tried to use "old" method and naming conventions to see how that works. In my application root directory I have launch images named :

- Default@2x.png which is 960x480px
- Default-568h@2x.png which is 1136x640px
- Default-667h@2x.png which is 1334x750px
- Default-736h@2x.png which is 2208x1242px

I've deleted LaunchScreen.xib file and removed "Launch screen interface file base name" property from info.plist.

What is happening is that 4s,5 and 5s simulators (both 7.1 and 8.1) pick up the right launch image. But the problem is with iPhone 6 and 6+ simulator. For example:

When iPhone 6 simulator is started there is no launch screen, just black screen... Why naming convention don't work for iPhone 6 and 6+? Device orientation is landscape.

Comment: have you in the general section of your iOS target have you set the launch image source to use asset catalogs? [screenshot here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/nnddq1foit6a1t4/Screen%20Shot%202015-02-08%20at%2009.50.21.png?dl=0) not the launch screen xib file

Comment: Yes, Launch Image Source = Use Asset Catalog, and Launch Screen File is empty. But I don't use Images.xcassets at all. I thought that is enough to have properly named images in application root? What is currently happening is that iPhone 6 simulator pick up Default-568h image instead of Default-667 and the scene is initialized wrong (568x320pts).

Comment: Also if I set Launch Screen File to some value, scene is initialized to proper size, but there is no launch screen at all, just black screen.

Comment: I've found a working solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25926661/how-do-i-create-launch-images-for-iphone-6-6-plus-landscape-only-apps/25960203#25960203