# iOS app using as3 not fitting screen dimensions

Tags: ios, iphone, actionscript-3, air, splash-screen

I'm building an iOS app using as3 and air to package the app onto my iPhone 6. My issue is that I get a black bar above and below the app, the app itself is not going fullscreen. The stage screen is set to the iPhone 6 screen dimensions.

I have tried by adding the following launch images into the app folder; Default-667h@2x.png, Default-568h@2.png, and Default@2x.png. In the AIR for iOS Settings under general, I've added them to the 'Included files' section but the bars are still there. [Dropbox link to image](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/41377970/IMG_1066.PNG).

Does anyone have any fixes for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iPhone 6 requires the Default image of Default-375w-667h@2x.png to be included. (and iPhone 6+ needs Default-414w-736h@3x.png).

This is a handy web page to bookmark which lists file sizes and names.
http://blog.tomasmahrik.com/list-of-properties-sizes-for-application-icons-launch-images-screenshots-video-previews-for-ios-air-apps/

Answer (score 0):

You should set your apps to not scale (looks like yours is scale to fit) and align top left:

```
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Resently had the same problem and splash screens didn't help. For me solution was only this [How do I create launch images for iPhone 6 / 6 Plus Landscape Only Apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25926661/how-do-i-create-launch-images-for-iphone-6-6-plus-landscape-only-apps)