# Launch screen view is misaligned in iOS 8 when having large status bar

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, statusbar

Why does the launch screen view get misaligned in iOS 8 when running the app with an enlarged status bar? See the attached image for details:

- The launch screen view seems to be cropped/resized from bottom by 20 pixels
- The Home screen background shows underneath (the red arrow)

[image]
The `LaunchScreen.xib` has auto layout enabled and `Info.plist` has the following settings:

- Status bar is initially hidden: `NO`
- View controller-based status bar appearance: `NO`
- Status bar style: `UIStatusBarStyleLightContent`

I'm using Xcode 6.3.1 (6D1002) and running the application in iPhone 6 with iOS 8.3.

Comment: sometimes 'clean project (also delete app from device)' fixes things like this. You can delete and add view too.

Comment: Did you added the launch image with proper dimensions? Look here if you miss that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25926661/how-do-i-create-launch-images-for-iphone-6-6-plus-landscape-only-apps

Comment: I'm not using a launch image, I'm using `LaunchScreen.xib` for creating the Launch Screen.

Comment: I deleted the app from the device, ran `clean`, but the result is the same. I'll try deleting the .XIB and recreating it.

Comment: I feel like this is a bug, I've seen this in my app and multiple other apps. I've noticed it a bit different though, there it seems to cut the image in the middle and bump the top half down.. I haven't looked into it but wanted to post in case it's a bug.

Comment: Still haven't figured out this - present in iOS 8.4 also.

Comment: Any new info here ?