# Xamarin App Keyboard is a different size to iOS Keyboard

Tags: ios, xamarin, keyboard, xamarin.ios

I'm developing an iOS app in Xamarin (**not using Forms, using Xamarin.iOS**) and I have noticed that the keyboard which appears in my Xamarin built app is larger than Keyboards which appear in other apps.

E.G. My app

[image]

E.G. Other iOS app (Apple Notes)

[image]

The numbers aren't really important, what is important is that there is definitely a difference in size between the two keyboards in terms of key height and key spacing.

There does not appear to be any obvious options or settings surrounding this. Trying different Keyboard Styles (I'm using "Default") does not solve the problem.

I would like to get my Keyboard to be the same size as a normal iOS App Keyboard.

---

**EDIT**

Krumelur's answer is correct.

This is how I specified the launch screens

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25960203/807836

In Visual Studio, there does appear to be an issue with this XML entry being lost if you edit the project file through the IDE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not Xamarin related. Your app is running in compatibility mode on an iPhone5 or 6. You will have to provide a launch screen for the particular device or a launch image to let iOS know you support the bigger screen.

See here on how to use [launch](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_images/launch-screens/) screens.