# Not able to set launch image for both portrait and landscape mode for iphone 4s, 5, 5s,6,6s

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode7.3

I am using Xcode 7.3 and have tried all the ways for setting the launch images,

1. one way I tried is creating a launch image in assets.xcassets and assigning the appropriate images.
2. second way I followed the link below,

[How do I create launch images for iPhone 6 / 6 Plus Landscape Only Apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25926661/how-do-i-create-launch-images-for-iphone-6-6-plus-landscape-only-apps/25960203#25960203)

By following the above link, I am able to set the launch image either portrait or landscape but not both.

Is there any possible way to set a launch image in both portrait and landscape for iPhone devices lesser than iPhone 6 plus?

Comment: use LaunchScreen.storyboard to set launch image.

Comment: @hardik by using launchscreen.storyboard, how can i set for both portrait and landscape.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using storyBoard??..
If you are using story then follow below steps:

1: first add launch screen Click command+n choose LaunchScreen and add.

2: Register the LaunchScreen.open info.plist follow this tutorials [https://useyourloaf.com/blog/using-a-launch-screen-storyboard/][1]

3:drag imageview on the launch screen and choose size class regular width and regular height then add leading, traling top and bottom constraint 0

Comment: the url link not found.